# Chain of hasMany or hasManyThrough through N models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, orm, eloquent

How can I get all the submissions belongs to a particular user? 
Trying this:

```
$user=User::find(1);        
dd($user->submissions);
```

Throwing error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::hasMany()
```

Will I have to loop through the models?

Here are the models:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements ConfideUserInterface, BillableInterface
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Category');
    }
    public function forms()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Form', 'Category');
    }

    public function submissions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Category')->hasMany('Form')->hasMany('Submission');
    }
}

class Category extends \Eloquent {
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
    public function forms()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Form');
    }
    public function submissions()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Submission', 'App\Models\Form', 'id', 'form_id');
    }
}

namespace App\Models;

class Form extends \Eloquent {
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->category->user();
    }
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Category');
    }
    public function submissions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Submission');
    }
}

class Submission extends \Eloquent {
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->form->category->user();
    }
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->form->category();
    }
    public function form()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Form');
    }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes on these complex model cases that have long relationship chains - I cheat and 'de-normalise' my database slightly - I just store the `user_ID` in the `submissions` table. Then you can easily get all submissions by that `user_ID`. Can actually be a performance boost as well in some cases depending how many joins there are etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't really work that way with chaining relations...

What you can do, is this:

```
$submissions = Submission::whereHas('form.category.user', function($q){
    $q->where('id', 1);
})->get();
```

**Note** that `whereHas` with nested relationships has only been added in the latest Laravel 4 release. Make sure to `composer update`.

Comment: How will it associate with a particular user id?

Comment: if I use your function and try to get submissions of a  `$user=User::find(1);        
$user->submissions;` , then how that can be?

Comment: If this is about the syntax, you can create a helper method or attribute access or in your model that returns the result of the query from my answer...

Comment: There is a typo `})` `;` `->get();`

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not getting your question wrongly, you need to define relationship correctly.

According to laravel 4.2 you can use below kind of code to define relations:

```
class User extends \Eloquent implements ConfideUserInterface, BillableInterface{
    //...

    public function submissions(){
        return $this->hasMany('Submission');
    }
}

//...

class Submission extends \Eloquent {
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
    //...
}
```

To further reading take a look at: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships

Comment: Your getting the question wrongly. The models `User` and `Submission` aren't directly related but rather over multiple relationships in between.

Comment: Right, No problem, can you please define your schema structure with relationship? so i can provide you model structure according schema..